# Non Archimedean countable models of the theory of the reals

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic, real-numbers

The questions in model theory I am trying to tackle is:
Show that there is a countable model of $Th(\langle \mathbb{R};+,.,-,-,1,< \rangle) $ which is non archimedean.

Honestly i dont really know what to do, i read in another stack exchange post that Th(R) is the set of all true first order sentences in the standard language that hold in the model R. Next, you notice that the standard language is itself countable and thus, applying Lowenheim-Skolem, you conclude that a countable model exists.

So i suppose that deals with countability, but what about the non archimedean property?

Comment: What is $Th$ ?;

Comment: The set of L sentences which are true in $\langle \mathbb{R};+,.,-,-,1,< \rangle) $

Comment: Incidentally, this theory is well-studied, and its models are called "real closed fields".

Answer (score 5):

We use *Compactness* and Lowenheim-Skolem.

Let $T$ be the set of sentences in our language $L$ that are true in the reals. Produce a new language $L'$ by adding the constant symbol $c$ to $L$. Produce a new theory $T'$ by adding to $T$ the axioms $1\lt c$, $1+1\lt c$, $1+1+1\lt c$, and so on. (We have left out some parentheses.)

Then any finite subset $F$ of $T'$ is consistent, since if the "largest" new axiom in $F$ is $n\lt c$, then we can produce a model of $F$ by letting the underlying set be the reals, and interpreting $c$ to be a large enough integer. So $T'$ is consistent, and therefore has a countable model by Lowenheim-Skolem. This is a countable non-Archimedean model of $T$.

Comment: It should be $n<c$ in the beginning of your second paragraph.

Comment: @Pece: Thank you, fixed.

Comment: I am sure this is the answer that the OP is looking for, but the field of Puiseux series over the algebraic reals provides a nice algebraic alternative.

Comment: Yes, there are more concrete (and therefore more illuminating) examples. But compactness gives an instantaneous solution. More interesting, from the point of view of Model Theory, are explicit characterizations of the definable subsets of the reals.

Comment: @Everybody: Oops! I meant to write "I am sure that this is *not* the answer the OP is looking for ...".

Comment: @RobArthan: There are too many Puiseaux series; they bump up the cardinality.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Once you have a non-archimedean model, you can find a countable non-archimedean model inside it as the real closure of $\Bbb{Q}(\epsilon)$ where $\epsilon$ is any infinitesimal or infinite element of the model. That's the "nice algebraic alternative" I had in mind. (It was a comment, not an answer.)